# Conversion tool for converting kubernetes yaml files from 1.15 to 1.17?

Tags: kubernetes

we are on kubernetes 1.15.* and our yaml files are incompatible with the latest 1.17 installation.

Is there an easy way of converting our yaml files with a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [kubeyaml](https://kubeyaml.com/) validator. It doesn't convert the yamls but it does show the exact errors for incompatible yaml for each version.